# spring-cloud-config-client - How to get a property from another application with a placeholder

Tags: spring-cloud-config

How to get a property from another application with a placeholder in a yml?
How would be the sintax?  Is that possible?

Looking for something like that: ${applicationName->property}

Answer (score 0):

I finally used a base /application.yml and a generic /configs/application.properties in the config server, where all properties in this file become public for all applications.

[image]

application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        prefix: /config
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/configs
```

/configs/application.properties:

```
adminPort=9898
```